# Prevent truncate without denying ALTER permission

Tags: permissions, alter-table, truncate

Is there a way to disallow users from truncating a table without denying ALTER permission on the table? Users should be able to maintain the standard ALTER permissions (adding columns to a table, etc.), but should be prevented from truncating the table.

Comment: If the table has foreign key referencing other tables then truncate will fail. Your best bet is to scrutinize it through a server side trace or revoke alter table or db_owner or sa permissions. Trigger does not work with truncate as Truncate is minimally logged and is a DDL operation.